# This expression is not callable. Type 'EditSectorNewsCreationProps' has no call signatures. ошибка при передаче функции в компонент

Tags: reactjs, typescript, компоненты, usestate

```
  const [validationType, changeValidationType] = useState(2);
  const setValidationType = (num: number) => {
    changeValidationType(num);
  };
я работаю с состояниями пытаюсь менять через дочерний компонент (
              <EditSector setValidationType={setValidationType} />
            )}
```

строка в компоненте, которая вызывает дочерний компонент

```
export const EditSector = (setValidationType: EditSectorNewsCreationProps) => {
  return (<Button
          onClick={() => setValidationType(2)}
          type='submit'
          buttonType={ButtonStyles.PLAN}
        >
          {PUBLICATION_PLAN_BUTTONS_TEXT}
        </Button>
```

компонент выглядит вот так внутри есть кнопка.
ну и соответственно интерфейс вот такой

```
export interface EditSectorNewsCreationProps {
  setValidationType: (num: number) => void;
}


This expression is not callable.
  Type 'EditSectorNewsCreationProps' has no call signatures.
```

как исправить данную ошибку?

пытался гуглить в интернете, ничего не смог найти, ответы лишь по типу функции, но вроде я написал правильно

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в этой строке

```typescript
onClick={() => setValidationType(2)}
```

Вы назвали **объект пропсов** `setValidationType`

```typescript
export const EditSector = (setValidationType: EditSectorNewsCreationProps) => {
```

Так как это **объект**, то вы не можете его вызывать. Сначала получите нужную функцию из пропсов:

```typescript
export const EditSector = (props: EditSeсtorNewsCreationProps) => {
    const { setValidationType } = props;
    // код дальше
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы говорите, что переменная **setValidationType** имеет следующий тип:

```
{
    setValidationType: (num: number) => void
}
```

т.е. вы пытаетесь сделать **{}()** - вызвать объект, как функцию, на что TS и ругается.

Вам нужен не интерфейс, а тип

```
export type EditSectorNewsCreationProps = (num: number) => void;
```

Если хотите работать с интерфейсом, то можно сделать так:

```
export const EditSector = (setValidationType: EditSectorNewsCreationProps['setValidationType'])
```

или так:

```
export const EditSector = ({ setValidationType }: EditSectorNewsCreationProps)
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, помогло, я пока новичок, многого не понимаю)